# Alternate URL for wikipedia commons page? Looks like an image file - breaks lightbox

Tags: html, http, lightbox

Is there an alternate way to link to wikipedia commons pages with more traditional URLs?

When I set the  href link on a lightbox image to be an external site page it's happy, unless the URL of that external page looks like an image (ends in '.jpg') - in which case the lightbox tries to load the image and breaks.

Wikipedia commons image pages act as pages, not images. 
I want to link to the page but the page URL ends with ".jpg" so lightbox is trying to load the page as an image.

Eg: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg

I have searched but can't find any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried URL-escaping the .jpg as a workaround?

Comment: Interesting problem, I fooled around a bit but I can't find an alternative source. You could place iframe the within another iframe, but it just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Patching lightbox is also an option, I suppose.

Comment: Did you try the image url itself? Eg [http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg) for the one linked above?

Comment: @Thilo URL-escaping doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to patch lightbox.

Comment: @roddy I need to link to the page and anything ending with .jpg screws it up.

Comment: What happens if you try to add a question mark after the url? As if passing an empty list of GET-parameters? (It might be a long shot, but maybe then Lightbox will not automatically assume it is a picture?)

Comment: Yet another example of why following HTTP standards helps everyone. The URL looks like the `File:*.jps` at the end is some kind of parameter. This problem could have been solved if the wikimedia creators used a more standard URL structure with GET parameters. E.g. `http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/viewFile.html?File=Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg`

Comment: How about just ending the URL with '?' I mean, `http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg?` doesn't end with .jpg now. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a #file at the end:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg#file

Answer from @Jesse may also be useful for some.

Answer (score 1):

I fooled around a little with the links on that page to see what they linked to...

Clicking on the "Discussion" tab at the top took me to this URL...

http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File_talk:Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg&action=edit&redlink=1

I tryed to play around with this URL a little...

- I changes the "File_talk" string to "File"
- I removed the "action" and "redlink" parameters

And Voila! An alternate URL that seems to work for the page you desire...

http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg

Comment: That's useful and led me to the (very simple) answer thanks. The above link doesn't work but if I put the hash/anchor on the end of the url it's fine! (I'm sure this will vary among lightbox types).
I used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_Haasts_eagle_attacking_New_Zealand_moa.jpg#file